# transaction in any payment gateway on admin approval

Tags: php, paypal, payment-processing

I want a feature like. If anyone wants to become feature on my website than he fills a form and pays the money. Now it will not be visible until admin approves it. So i want to do it like the money should be deducted only when the admin approves it. So is there such kind of facility in any payment gateway to do such delayed transaction. or any other way in which i can do this... Is it good to store the card holder information in md5 and later doing the transaction when admin approves it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store a credit card number using MD5. [MD5 is one way hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). That means once you hash it you cannot get the original value back. You would need to use an encryption algorithm if you wanted to have the encrypted value unencrypted at any point in the future.

And if you store credit card information you will be subject to [PCI compliance](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/). PCI compliance is not easy to do.

If you're looking to store credit card information to charge a customer at a future date you can use a service like [Authorize.Net's Customer Information Manager (CIM)](http://developer.authorize.net/api/cim/). CIM allows you to store credit card information on Authorize.Net's server so you don't have to worry about PCI compliance. Then you can charge users at a future date safely and securely.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal preapproved payments (card details stored with PayPal. Buyer gives approval to you to bill them up to a certain ceiling, you use this approval 'ID' to bill the buyer) and/or reference transactions would work in this case. 
I'd very strongly advise against storing card details on your end; it'll cause more headaches than it's worth. Bigger companies have tried, and failed.